# Closure in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I am new to Groovy. I execute the following Groovy code:

```
myList=[234, 34, "Stackoverflow", 3.14]

myList=myList.collect {if (it instanceof Integer) it*it}     

println myList
```

it outputs:

```
[54756, 1156, null, null]
```

It seems to me that it shouldn't change the strings value. when I change the second line to:

```
myList=myList.collect {if (it instanceof Integer) it*it else it=it}
```

it works as I expected:

```
[54756, 1156, Stackoverflow, 3.14]
```

I am wondering what is the logic behind that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is no `else` clause in your first version, `null` is the result.

The second version should work like this, too:

```
myList.collect {if (it instanceof Integer) it * it else it}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the reason is because you have not specified the outcome of the first closure in case an element is not an Integer and it defaulted to null

```
​println a()

def a() {
   if (1==2) "Hello!"
}​

>> null
```